# How to add keep alive in Websocket in JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, performance-testing

We need to add keep-alive for websocket with timeout value in JMeter.

Pls assist us how to add the same in JMeter.

Without this, we are facing socket Closed error during load test.

Tried adding Connection: keep-alive header

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please have a read on [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What failed? What did you try? What did you research? How does your code/implementation look like? This is way to vague, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box JMeter doesn't support [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) so you will need either a library or a plugin for load testing WebSockets with JMeter.

Once you choose a library or a plugin you will need to consult its documentation for details on how to set up the connection and when and how to close it.

For example if you go for [WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) you will have **WebSocket Open Connection** sampler where you can specify protocol, host, port, path and timeouts:

[image]

in other Samplers which will be doing the real job you will be able to choose `use existing connection` option:

[image]

the connection will remain open until the thread is alive or you decide to close it explicitly.

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)

Comment: Dmitri: I am aware that you answer any question with Jmeter in it, but it helps SO (and SQA for that matter) when questions are of some quality and this one is clearly not.